# Relationship between *Helicobacter pylori* and stomach acid

Tags: stomach, acidic, proton-pump-inhibitors, helicobacter-pylori, antacid

Omeprazole (or another proton pump inhibitor) is often used to treat patients diagnosed with *Helicobacter pylori*. I have heard of people treated this way and there's a [study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9777317) which suggests doing so. The drug reduces gastric acid secretion.

On the other hand, I found tons of non-scientific articles, e.g. [here](http://www.bewellnaturallyguide.com/is-low-stomach-acid-the-cause-of-h-pylori/), suggesting that the bacteria thrives when the stomach acid level is low. If this is the case, **why is it treated with antacids?**

I found lot of scientific papers on the subject, but I find them incomprehensible. Could someone explain in plain English?